# Persistence provider caller does not implement the EJB3 spec

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x

WARN  [Ejb3Configuration] Persistence provider caller does not
 implement the EJB3 spec correctly. PersistenceUnitInfo.getNewTempClassLoad
er() is null.

How do you get rid of the above warning?

```
0:42:08,032 INFO  [PersistenceUnitDeployment] Starting persistence unit pe
rsistence.unit:unitName=k12-ear.ear/k12-ejb-1.0.0.jar#k12
10:42:08,371 INFO  [Version] Hibernate Annotations 3.4.0.GA
10:42:08,442 INFO  [Environment] Hibernate 3.3.1.GA
10:42:08,450 INFO  [Environment] hibernate.properties not found
10:42:08,486 INFO  [Environment] Bytecode provider name : javassist
10:42:08,492 INFO  [Environment] using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
10:42:08,754 INFO  [Version] Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.1.0.GA
10:42:08,989 INFO  [Version] Hibernate EntityManager 3.4.0.GA
10:42:09,211 INFO  [Ejb3Configuration] Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: k12
        ...]
10:42:09,458 WARN  [Ejb3Configuration] Persistence provider caller does not
 implement the EJB3 spec correctly. PersistenceUnitInfo.getNewTempClassLoad
er() is null.
10:42:09,620 WARN  [Ejb3Configuration] Defining hibernate.transaction.flush
_before_completion=true ignored in HEM
10:42:09,745 DEBUG [AnnotationConfiguration] Execute first pass mapping pro
cessing
```

Comment: @Joshua JBoss App server ? Which version ?

Comment: JBoss 5.1.0, Hibernate 3.3.2.GA